# .htaccess not allowing sub-directory to work

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|index.php|administrator|system|template|js|lib|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?tpl=$1 [L]


Options +FollowSymlinks
```

However what is happening is that all the following folders wont allow me to go into them and view a PHP file.

```
|administrator|system|template|js|lib
```

I thought by putting the files in `RewriteCond` that it would allow a user to still go to `http://example.com/news/happy` which then would go to the index.php?tpl=etc etc but it has stopped me from going into any subdirectory like

http://example.com/system/index.php

Comment: Did you check if on other subdirectories you have other .htaccess files with another rules?

Comment: No other subdirectories have .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work for you. But what I do is to add this rules to load calls to any .php file without the .php ending. You can call both, with or without that ending.

For example, you can call `my_url.com/myfolder/myfile` and it will load `myfile.php`, with the friendly URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: do I put that in sub-directory

Comment: Nop. On the root directory it should work well. .htaccess files work recursively unless there is another file that would replace those rules.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to recommend that you read about mod rewrite first

1 - put that line at top

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
```

That line ask your server to follow symlinks but i would like recommend that you use the more secure option "SymLinksIfOwnerMatch"

Source:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options#FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Enables or disables runtime rewriting engin

Source:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine

```
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|index.php|administrator|system|template|js|lib|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
```

Here you go . that rule ask the web server to add rewrite Condition to ignore everything listed in your regex

also i have added regex explain for you

```
 !
```

not equal 
     ^
Start with

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?tpl=$1 [L]
```

you are asking  to write everything else to index.html?tpl=$1
** I think you mean index.php i will assume that you don't need the query string

i would like to recommend using a better way to handle the excluding

```
 RewriteEngine On
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.html|index.php|administrator|system|template|js|lib|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?tpl=$1 [L]
```